# Why I shouldn't use blockingGet() if I am using Single<> and what are the replacements

Tags: java, rx-java

Why I shouldn't use `blockingGet()` if I am using `Single<>` and what are the replacements of it.

I have

```
PaymentEntity payment= paymentsRepository.getById(id).blockingGet();
```

the `getById()` returns a `Single<PaymentEntity>`

```
Single<PaymentEntity> getById(String Id);
```

One of my colleagues told me that i must not use `blockingGet()`, without any clear reasons.

So why I shouldn't use `blockingGet()` if I am using `Single<>` and what are the replacements of it?

Comment: Why are you using `blockingGet` in the first place? Have you heard about `subscribe`?

Comment: @akarnokd I need the internal PaymentEntity. How i can get the PaymentEntity?

Comment: @Antoniossss , cool, then i well use subscribe . But do know why i shouldn't use blockingGet() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `subscribe` to get it.

Why? To not block the execution of calling thread. Otherwise what is the point of using rx? Unless you *really must block the execution* dont do it.

Comment: 'subscribe' returns 'Disposable' but i need to return 'PaymentEntity'

Comment: `subscribe` takes callback in which you are supossed to do the job. Its reactive programming principia.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but i ended up using map instead of subscribe